# Can Eclipse automatically continue my comment block prefix when I hit ENTER?

Tags: c++, eclipse

If I have a comment block like:

```
/// @brief This is a documentation block.
///
/// @param foo Documentation of Foo.
```

When I hit ENTER to keep adding content to this comment block, it would be nice if Eclipse could automatically begin the line with `///` at the correct indentation level. Visual Assist for Visual Studio has this feature and it's nice. Is there a plugin or built in option that will enable this behavior?

Comment: Eclipse does that automatically for comment blocks that begin with `/*` and `/**`. Don't know about `///` soz. But you can do `CTRL-/` to toggle `//` style comments on multiple selected lines.